.Net Core 8.0 Web API installer closes immediately
I've create 2 project in a solution with VS2022.

Weatherforecast web api (as provided by microsoft)
Microsoft setup project extension (To create exe /msi for that).

To create this setup project what I tried is as below -

Added project output as publish item.


I want to create locally shareable web api installer.
I am able to install msi and run my web api locally on my laptop. But when I send this exe and try to install this, web api suddenly run and stop.

After testing in my local, I found the reason is missing .net runtime in your new machine.
You can verify it by checking the EventViewer Logs.

I got same results. Thanks! Just need to automate .net runtime for it.
